# TYPO3: How to use file upload with extbase?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I'm building a simple extension based on extbase / fluid which has an
upload form in a frontend plugin. It was working in 6.0.4, but now I get
the following exception when I try to upload a file:

> #1297759968: Exception while property mapping at property path "fichier":No converter found which can be used to convert from "array"
>   to "string".

The problem seems to be related to the fact that the web request
receives an array for the uploaded file, but the model stores it as a
string. How can I get rid of this exception? How should I handle file
upload in extbase?

---

The extension was started using `Extension Builder`. `fichier` is a string property in the Model, containing the name of the uploaded file (located into `uploads/tx_myext/`). The template for the plugin contains an upload field build from a `form.upload` ViewHelper. On TYPO3 6.0.4, when I submit the form, I receive an object as argument to the `createAction` function. From that object, I call `getFichier` that returns me the file array of the uploaded file. Then, I can extract the original file name, copy the temp file to the right location, and set the value of the `fichier` property using the original file name.

Now, in TYPO3 6.1.0, I get the above exception before entering the `createAction` function. My guest is that PropertyMapper is trying to translate the file array to a string to match the type of `fichier` property.

What I don't know is was the way it worked before was a bug, or is it the way it works now that is the bug. And if it really works the way it is intended to do, how should I be able to handle file upload in an extbase extension?

Comment: you need to give more details

Comment: I added some details. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```php
 /**
 * initialize actions
 */
public function initializeAction() {
    if ($this->arguments->hasArgument('myModel')) {
        $this->arguments->getArgument('myModel')->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()->setTargetTypeForSubProperty('upload', 'array');
    }
}
```

http://www.typo3lexikon.de/typo3-tutorials/extensions/extbase/property-mapper.html

Comment: It probably worth pointing out that `initializeAction` is called for each action of the Controler, and that `myModel` refers to the name of the variable given to the `createAction()` function.